# Inject .html file from packed chrome extension directory into new window tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, document.write, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a Chrome extension (v3) and I am trying to load an `index.html` from the extension's directory, and replace the old html with my html in a newly created window. But instead of html, it gets rendered as text. This is what I got so far:

I stored the html file in my **background.js** :

```js
let template = chrome.runtime.getURL("assets/index.html");

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( () => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ "data": {"template" : template } });
});
```

In my **popup.js**, I first created a new window. Then I tried to inject a content script that overwrites the current html with my `index.html` file, as seen below:

```js
button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  //get url of current tab
  let tab = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  //create new window
  let newWindow = await chrome.windows.create({
    url : tab[0].url,
    type : "popup",
    width: dims.cssWidth,
    height: dims.cssHeight,
    state: "normal"
  })

  const tabId = newWindow.tabs[0].id;
  if (!newWindow.tabs[0].url) await onTabUrlUpdated(tabId);

  const results = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId},
      function: setBackground,
  });

});
```

**setBackground()** function to remove existing html and replace it, but keep url `tab[0].url` from active page to embed it as an iframe

```js
function setBackground(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get("data", ({ data }) => {
      document.write(data.template);
      //add tab[0].url as iframe
  });
}
```

How can I replace the new window with my own html rather than render text?

Comment: @wOxxOm I added more info to the popup.js code, hope that makes things clearer

Comment: chrome.runtime.getURL generates a URL by adding chrome-extension://id/ to the parameter. It doesn't read the contents of the URL. Use `fetch` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Can I `fetch` either in `background.js` or content script? Why would you do one over the other?

Comment: Do it in the background script.

Answer (score 1):

One way of reading the contents of a local `.html` file with `fetch` would be the following:

```js
function setBackground(){
      try {
        //fetch local asset
        const res = await fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("/assets/index.html"));
        const myhtml = await res.text()
        document.write(myhtml);

      } catch(err){
          console.log("fetch error", err);
      }

}
```